# Is it ok to replace less with less than in (ε, δ)-definition of limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

Definition:

> Let f(x) be a function defined on an interval that contains x=a,
> except possibly at x=a . Then we say that,if for every number ε>0
> there is some number δ>0 such that
>
> $$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon
> \hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
> \right| < \delta$$

**My question is whether I can change the def to the following**
1):
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| <= \varepsilon
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| <= \delta$$
2):
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| <= \delta$$
3):
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| <= \varepsilon
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| < \delta$$

**If not, could you please provide an counter-example?** It seems all ok to me. But I am not certain.

Comment: They are all equivalent.

Comment: ^ and it's a good exercise for you to see why they're all equivalent

Comment: @peek-a-boo I will try to prove myself. thanks. I am watching khanacademy calculus. The question always popup in my head over and over.  : )

Comment: Hint: If you know that something is $\leq\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, but then you want $<\varepsilon$ instead, just think about the fact that this holds for *all* $\varepsilon > 0$ -- what can you do to $\delta$ to change that $\leq$ into $<$?

Comment: @HansLundmark Yes. Totally. Thanks a lot. My question is the same as this one.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| <= \varepsilon
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| <= \delta$$

According to this def, since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary small. Given $\varepsilon$ we can find a $\varepsilon_1$<$\varepsilon$ which also meet the condition. In this case:
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon_1
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| <= \delta_1$$

When $0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| <= \delta_1$, the $\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon_1$ will always fullfill. So when pick a number $\delta_2$<$\delta_1$,$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon_1$ still holds.

Thus we have:
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon_1
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| < \delta_2$$

This could also be represented as
$$\left| {f\left( x \right) - L} \right| < \varepsilon
\hspace{0.5in}{\mbox{whenever}}\hspace{0.5in}0 < \left| {x - a}
\right| < \delta$$